# Combination Question: How to answer an exam of 15 questions but having to answer 10 of them with the following resitrctions?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

a) You must answer 2 of the first three, 1 of the next 3, and 7 of the remaining 9?

b) Answer any 5 of even numbered and 6 of any odd numbers

c) If you answer question 1 you are not allowed to answer question 3

Here is my thought process: 
a) (3C2)(3C1)(9C7)
b)(7C5)(8C5)
c) (14C10)

I am not confident in my answers and would like someone to walk me through this question

Comment: For b, I think you mean $_8C_6$.

Comment: Something's wrong with b). That's 11 questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) Your answer is correct.  Pick two of the three questions from the first section, then pick one of the three questions from the next section, then seven of the questions from the final section.  Multiply the number of ways to select from each respective section to get

$$\binom{3}{2}\binom{3}{1}\binom{9}{7}$$

(b) There must be a typo in the question.  What is probably intended is to select five questions from the seven even numbered questions, and **five** questions from the eight odd numbered questions.  In that case, your answer is correct.

$$\binom{7}{5}\binom{8}{5}$$

(c) We are tasked here with finding the number of ways of choosing ten questions so that **if** question $1$ was answered, then question $3$ is not answered.  It is allowed to answer question $1$ so long as question $3$ was not answered, just as it is allowed to answer question $3$ so long as question $1$ was not answered.  It is also allowed to have answered neither.

We can approach from a number of different ways.  We can count the number of ways of having answered $1$ and not $3$, add this to the number of ways of having answered $3$ and not $1$, and add this to the number of ways of having answered neither, giving a total of:

$$\binom{13}{9}+\binom{13}{9}+\binom{13}{10}$$

We could also have approached this as counting the number of ways of having answered $1$ and nine others not including $3$, adding this to the number of ways of having answered $10$ others not including $1$, giving a total of:

$$\binom{13}{9}+\binom{14}{10}$$

Or, yet another way we could have approached is by counting the number of ways of selecting ten to answer and removing the "bad" ways where we answered both $1$ and $3$, giving a total of:

$$\binom{15}{10}-\binom{13}{8}$$

All of which give the same final answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, c was giving me a lot of troubles and was not sure how to approach. I really do appreciate your help!